# iPhone UI Automation unrestricted to a single app

Tags: ios, xcode, ui-automation, ui-testing

I hope this is not a duplicate, but I couldn't find what I'm interested in.

I'm trying to build some automated tests that will use an iPhone. The best tool I can find for this seems to be UI Automation, but from what I can tell so far, I need to run it against a specific app. My tests need to be more general. For example, I want to be able to answer an incoming call in the default dialer.

I would like to be able to automate the iPhone itself, not a specific app. My tests might involve switching between apps or making calls. The main features I need are to be able to take a screenshot and touch certain coordinates on the screen, regardless of what is on the screen and running at the time.

Can anyone suggest the proper way to set this up? I'd like to use the supported UI Automation tools, but would like to use them in a more general way.

Thanks